# How to store NSDictionary in iCloud

Tags: objective-c, icloud

I'm new to iCloud integration, I did found some tutorials but I still couldn't get the solution I want.

I found that there are 3 ways of saving the data to the iCloud

1) Key-Value

2) Core-Data

3) UIDocument

I don't really know which is the best option for me. All I want is just save a few NSDictionary to iCloud. Can anyone tell me how can I do that and which option should I use?

Basically I will have 2 to 3 NSDictionary. Each of NSDictionary might be holding about 50+ pairs of data and I wanna save them into iCloud so that other devices can retrieve the same NSDictionary.

Please help.

Comment: Use key value. It will be simpliest way.

Comment: How to use key value? I don't understand.

Comment: for storing `NSDictionary` (or any customised) objects, you have to use the `UIDocument` class.

Comment: @Flink, in that case the `KV` way is useless...

Answer (score 0):

Key Value is limited for small sized amounts of data: the total space available in your app’s iCloud key-value storage is 1 MB per user. The maximum number of keys you can specify is 1024, and the size limit for each value associated with a key is 1 MB.
I suggest creating a UIDocument subclass incorporating your NSDictionary objects and use this solution.

A good idea is to begin reading Apple documentation for iCloud storage:
https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/

Comment: I don't really understand how to calculate the storage size. Let say I have a NSDictionary,
Inside contains 50 keys and the data type that paired with the keys are all NSNumber only.
So how much does the NSDictionary has occupied the storage?

Comment: I don't think it's a matter of how much space but of functionality. Key Value is intended to be used to share user defaults and not much more between iCloud enabled devices. Consider what is the function of the NSDictionary you need: using UIDocument is much more flexible and it's more appropriate if these are user data.